# create a flag for each month policy is active

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset with policies date began between 2018-01-01 and 2019-12-31 (2 years) that has the following info:

```
policy          policy_beg_date    policy_end_date
a                 01-01-2018         06-02-2018
b                 04-02-2019         02-04-2020
c                 23-12-2019         03-02-2020
d                 02-02-2019
```

policy begining date (date that policy started) and policy end date (date that policy ended - is missing if policy is still active)

I would like to create flags of 13 months (flag_0month, flag_1month,....flag_13month) where i give 1 if policy is active in month 0, month1, and so on.... where month0 is the month of beginnig, month1 is month of begining + 1 and so on so i would have something like this:

```
policy          policy_beg_date    policy_end_date  month_begining   month_end  act_month0  act_month1  act_month2
a               01-01-2018           06-01-2018       201801          201801       1              
b               04-02-2019           02-04-2020       201902          202003       1              1          1
c               23-12-2019           03-02-2020       201912          202002       1              1          1
d               02-02-2019                            201902                       1              1          1
```

Can anyone please help me achivieng this?

I already tryied someting like in this post : https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-create-a-flag-for-each-month-lying-between-2-d... but i get errors and i think it's not the same as i need.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
data have ;
  infile cards truncover ;
  input policy : $1. policy_beg_date : ddmmyy10. policy_end_date : ddmmyy10. ;
  format policy_beg_date policy_end_date date9. ;
datalines ;
a 01-01-2018 06-02-2018
b 04-02-2019 02-04-2020
c 23-12-2019 03-02-2020
d 02-02-2019    
e 01-01-2020 31-01-2020
;
run;

data want ;
  set have ;
  /* use intck() to get # months */  
  months = intck('month',policy_beg_date,min(policy_end_date,date())) ;
  
  /* array to hold the flags */
  array act{0:13} act_month0-act_month13 ;

  /* loop from 0 to months, set the array flags */
  do mn = 0 to min(months,hbound(act)) ;
    act{mn} = 1 ;
  end ;
run ;

proc print noobs ; run ;
```

[image: Results]